# How to make image link to (be clickable) to page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I am using CarrierWave and Amazon S3 to upload images to my application, which is working correctly. But I also want to have the image link to the corresponding Movie. I have tried the following but it doesn't work. I have looked but can't seem to find a solution this simple problem.

```
    <% if @movie.avatar? %>
      <%= image_tag(@movie.avatar_url), link_to @movie %>
    <% else %>
      <a href="<%= link_to @movie.name %>"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x200"></a>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(@movie.avatar_url), @movie %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
<%= link_to (image_tag(@movie.avatar_url)), @movie %>
```